# Validate Array JSON response with Multiple records in Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have API which gives following responses

```
[
        {
            "subject": "English",            
            "Marks": "79"
        },
        {
           "subject": "Maths",            
            "Marks": "89"

        }
    ]
```

We need to validate that
Subject=English and Marks =79
Subject=Maths and Marks =89

we have tried but not successful.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strindentify);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String type = jsonobject.getString("subject");
                Assert.assertEquals(type, "English");
                String value = jsonobject.getString("Marks");
                Assert.assertEquals(value, "79");
                System.out.println(" The Subject and Marks:-" +type +"and" +value );
            }
```

Need to assert that Subject=English then Marks=79 etc

Comment: I believe you meant to say *"Need to assert that **if** Subject=English then Marks=79"*. That missing "if" is the keyword here, because to do that, you'd need an `if` statement in your code, and I don't see any of those. Try again.

Comment: Can we get a view on your imports or the origin of `hasItem(String)` in this test case?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your assertion. You have to pass 2 strings to **assertEquals**:

```
Assert.assertEquals(type, "English");
```

Comment: Without knowing the origin of `hasItem()` you can't be certain that a String is not being passed in as argument. As far as you see `hasItem()` may return a String value. Although it seems inefficient at best this may be valid.

Comment: But type is string var. and you have to just check equality of 2 strings.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but consider the following `public String hasItem(String input) { return input; }`. This is why I said it's inefficient. This example would work in the case (despite everything that's wrong with it).

Comment: @Haris We have modified the script pls check

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop checks both subjects in each iteration. Instead you will want to get the single values of 'subject' and 'marks' in each iteration, and check your conditions based on the subject.

Such as:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(strindentify);

Assert.assertEquals(2, jsonarray.length, "Expected exactly 2 entries in array"); //optional

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String type = jsonobject.getString("subject");
    String value = jsonobject.getString("Marks");
    System.out.println(" The Subject and Marks:-" +type +"and" +value );
    
    switch(type) {
         case "English": Assert.assertEquals(value, "79"); break;
         case "Maths": Assert.assertEquals(value, "89"); break;
         default: throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected subject"); //optional
    }
}
```

Note the '//optional' lines, which respectively will fail the test if there is anything more or less than 2 items in the array, or if any subject other than English or Maths is encountered.
Note that this doesn't fail the edge case where the array contains 2 entries, but both are English or both are Maths.

I used a `switch` which would allow you to easily add other subjects/marks combinations. An if/else construct would be just as valid. Just remember to `break` if you use `switch`!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void test_validJson() {
    String input = "Your_string_json_here";
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(input);
    Assert.assertNotNull(jsonarray);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        Assert.assertNotNull(jsonobject);
        String subject = jsonobject.getString("subject");
        String value = jsonobject.getString("Marks");
        Assert.assertNotNull(subject);
        Assert.assertNotNull(value);
        switch(subject) {
            case "English" : 
                Assert.assertEquals(value, "79");
                break;
            case "Maths" :
                Assert.assertEquals(value, "89");
                break;
            default: 
            // Fail on unrecognized subject?
            throw new AssertionException();
        }
     }
}
```

Note that this will fail if the subject and/or value is missing and will also fail on unknown subject(s). This makes no guarantees for the length of the array or the ordering of the elements, eg English MUST be the first array item etc. Duplicate subjects will also not fail the test.This simply validates that if given subjects are included in the response then their respective marks are as those given.

Modify this to your liking.

EDIT:
If you want to validate only selected subjects are included:

```
List<String> knownSubjects = Arrays.asList("History", "Maths", "English", "whatever");
Assert.assertTrue(knownSubjects.contains(subject));
```

If you want to validate only known subjects WITH known marks:

```
Map<String, String> subjectMarks = new HashMap<>();
subjectMarks.put("English", "89");
subjectMarks.put("Maths", "79");
subjectMarks.put("Whatever", "10");

Assert.assertTrue(subjectMarks.keySet().contains(subject));
Assert.assertEquals(value, subjectMarks.get(subject));
```

Comment: if subject is not fixed then switch statement will not work , lets say subject added as History,Science,geography etc. We have used the if and else statement but need dynamic subject

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. If you have a list of subjects that should be accepted I have modified my question to include that test case. If you want to include mark tests as well for that array (a given subject has a given mark) you need to use a different data model.